# When I close the lid of my HP Zbook v15 the screen goes off but the laptop doesn't suspend/hibernate!

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, laptop, lid

I am working with a HP Zbook 15 Workstation with Ubuntu 18.04 installed. When I close my laptop lid the screen goes black but doesn't suspend. When I open it again I don't have to login or anything.

I have tried many things including editing `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and installing gnome tweaks and selecting "suspend when laptop lid is closed" but nothing works.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: what is your RAM size?

Comment: It is 16 Gigabytes

Comment: And your swap size?

Comment: The swap is 2 GB, I believe

Comment: Normally it should be half the size of the RAM, perhaps that should be the first step!

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying varies things I found that adding `acpi=force` to the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` in `/etc/default/grub` did the trick.

So for anyone running Ubuntu 18.04 on a HP Zbook v15 use:

`sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`

and change the line that reads `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` to:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=force"`

Comment: I make your ttitle more detailed to help others with same laptop. Please remember to click grey check mark next to your answer so others know it works.